# How can I get acces to the solve error value in the clip editor, and the projection error from trackers in python?

Tags: python, scripting, tracking

How can I access the solve error value generated from the "Solve Camera Motion" in Blender using a Python script? Additionally, how do I retrieve the projection error for each tracker through Python?

Comment: I don't think there is any api that exposes the camera solve error

Comment: Do you know any other way I could get the solve error in python?

Comment: No I don't think it's possible.